# Replace all the hex by decimal in a file

Tags: python, search, replace, hex

I would like to replace all the hex by their decimal equivalent in a .sql file.

I have hundreds of thousands of lines like this one :

```
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST_ID, VEHICLE_ID, TEST_TYPE_ID, TYPE_ID, NUM_TEST, TEST_DATE, HOUR_START, HOUR_END, ....) VALUES (844, 504, 3, 1, 3, CAST(0x0000991400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009914008FC76C AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000991400906924 AS DateTime), ......);
```

And I would like to use this sql file to create a SQLite database. But SQLite doesn't recognize the hex. So the objective is to replace all the hex of the file.

I found this solution to replace a specific hex :

```
decimal = int("0x0000991400000000", 0)
```

And I found this solution to replace all the occurrences of a word by another one :

```
for line in fileinput.input():
line = re.sub('wordToReplace','newWord', line.rstrip())
```

I tried to use the first one in the second one but 'newWord' is exepecting a string and I am giving an int. What could be a way to do what I want ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: `str(int)` will stringfy the integer.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: The file is more than 477 MB with almost 300 000 lines "INSERT TO..." and each line has 6 CAST with a hex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a replacement function with regex:

```
import re

data = "INSERT INTO TEST (TEST_ID, VEHICLE_ID, TEST_TYPE_ID, TYPE_ID, NUM_TEST, TEST_DATE, HOUR_START, HOUR_END, ....) VALUES (844, 504, 3, 1, 3, CAST(0x0000991400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009914008FC76C AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000991400906924 AS DateTime), ......);"

data_dec = re.sub("(0x[\dA-F]+)",lambda m : str(int(m.group(1),16)),data)

print(data_dec)
```

result:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST_ID, VEHICLE_ID, TEST_TYPE_ID, TYPE_ID, NUM_TEST, TEST_DATE, HOUR_START, HOUR_END, ....) VALUES (844, 504, 3, 1, 3, CAST(168311178395648 AS DateTime), CAST(168311187818348 AS DateTime), CAST(168311187859748 AS DateTime), ......);
```

When the hex number regex (`"(0x[\dA-F]+)"`) is found, the `lambda` is called with the match as argument. Take the first & only group, parse it as base-16 integer, then convert it back to string.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Jean-François. Is it possible to use a file example.sql as data instead of a string, and so directly modify the file ? I tried to do it using myFile = raw_input(example.sql) and then data = open(myFile, "r"). I have something wrong.

Comment: you mean `data = open(myFile, "r").read()` else you get the handle, not the contents.

Comment: Okay great I got it ! Thank you very much, it's the result I wanted. And with an explanation of how the code works. Perfect, have a nice week-end !